# How should the mapping done for the many to many relationship in hibernate for this?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

First of all i want to tell i am new to hibernate.

i have gone through tutorials such as one-one mapping,one-many mapping etc. but still i have query as,

i have 3 tables as:

```
Users                            Dealfollows                         Deal
=========                        ============                        ============     
userid(PK)                       dealid(FK)                          dealid(PK) 
firstname                        userid(FK)                          name
lastname                                                             description
..                                                                   ..
```

So i am having problem is that when i make dealid & userid as PK along with FK in dealfollows table hibernate code generation tool does not generate pojo class & hbm file for dealfollows 
So i want to save/update each of this entity separately
Users - save/update individually
Deal- save/update individually
Dealfollows - when user selects a particular deal then & then only i want to save/update it here

Help me for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dealfollows is a simple link table. hibernate allows you to not have to declare an entity for this but rather a manytomany and handles the crud itself. eg these classes are enough

```
class User
{
    Set<Deal> deals;
}

class Deal
{
    Set<User> users;
}
```